# Similair linear gradient in the top and bottom

Tags: html, css

How can make the same linear gradient of the top of my div in the bottom of the div

here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/36QqA/1/) i just make the top i want the same at the bottom of my div

HTML :

```
<div></div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, rgb(215, 223, 236) 10%);
    border: 1px gray solid;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/36QqA/2/)

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        white, 
        rgb(215, 223, 236) 10%,
        rgb(215, 223, 236) 90%,
        white);
    border: 1px gray solid;

}
```

Comment: I assure you they are the same.

Comment: no i think the effect is not the same. can anyone confirm it ?

Comment: It's an optical illusion I suspect but whatever, See  http://jsfiddle.net/36QqA/4/

Comment: hhh it's weird i'm sure it's not the same effect.